# Loop on json data

Tags: javascript, json, linq, loops, for-loop

trying to loop to get my datas:

```
$.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: '',
    dataType: 'json',
    data: {
           Id: id
           },
    success: function (data) {
        var detaildata = '';
        var obj = data;
        for (var m in obj)
        {
            detaildata = detaildata + obj[m];
        }
     },
     error: function (ex) {
        var r = "There is a problem";
        alert("Message: " + r);
     }
});
```

Output:
[object Object][object Object][object Object][object Object]

At least, number of object is correct (4).

My object is coming from a linq query:

```
var queryList = (from media in _context.Medias
    where media.ProductId == Id
    orderby media.MediaOrder
    select new
    {
        MediaName = "<div><img src='https://www.example.com/img/" + media.MediaName + "' class='img - thumbnail' style='width: 150px' /></div>"
    }).ToList();
```

If I take it as .FirstOrDefault() and don't loop, output is perfect!

Comment: You're appending an object to a string.. the output you're receiving is correct. What is it that you are trying to do?

Comment: Post an example of your object. If it is an array of objects that have a `value` key you need to do `detaildata = data.map(item => item.value).join(",")` for example

Comment: Thanks @HymnZzy, I did add some details.

Comment: @Philippe .. what is the output you're looking at? What's your reasoning behind `detaildata = detaildata + obj[m];` this line?

Comment: output is a list of photos: <div><img src='https://www.example.com/img/dataname.jpg' class='img - thumbnail' style='width: 150px' /></div>

Comment: Can you share a sample of `data` as well?

Comment: @HymnZzy, just did. Do you want to go through with chat?

Comment: @Philippe .. I can't see the new edits.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/225456/discussion-between-hymnzzy-and-philippe).

Answer (score 1):

Assuming your JSON is like this:

```
var data=  {
        "datas": [
                  { "FirstName":"John" , "LastName":"Doe" },
                  { "FirstName":"Anna" , "LastName":"Smith" },
                  { "FirstName":"Peter" , "LastName":"Jones" }
                 ]
           }
```

Then you can query like this:

```
$.each(data.datas, function(index,data) {        
    alert(data.FirstName+" "+data.LastName)
});
```

sample:

```
http://jsfiddle.net/4HxSr/9/
```

Comment: Thanks @Nandan, I did add some details about my object

Answer (score 0):

Your loop logic is not complete. As per the linq query, the output is an array of JSON objects with property `MediaName`. You'll need specify the property to extract the links. Try this.

```
$.ajax({
  type: 'POST',
  url: '',
  dataType: 'json',
  data: {
    Id: id
  },
  success: function (data) {
    var detaildata = data.map((obj)=>{ return obj['MediaName'] }); // for array
  },
  error: function (ex) {
    var r = "There is a problem";
    alert("Message: " + r);
  }
});
```

use `var detaildata = data.reduce((str,obj)=>{ return str+obj['MediaName'] });` if you want the output in a string

Answer (score 0):

Finally got it work simply with:

```
detaildata = "<div class='row'>";
for (var m in data)
{
    detaildata = detaildata + data[m]['MediaName'];
}
detaildata = detaildata + "</div>";
```

Thanks @HymnZzy for your help.